# How to localize DataAnnotations from both SharedSource.resx AND ViewModel.resx

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, .net-core

In [.Net Core official documentation for localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization), it is mentioned how to make `DataAnnotations` to be localized by `IStringLocalizer` from either a special `resx` file named by special .Net Core naming convention:

> For example:
>   Resources/ViewModels.Account.RegisterViewModel.fr.resx
>   Resources/ViewModels/Account/RegisterViewModel.fr.resx

or from `SharedResource.resx` file, from where **ALL** DataAnnotations will be localized:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
            options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
        });
}
```

> In the preceeding code, SharedResource is the class corresponding to the resx where your validation messages are stored. With this approach, DataAnnotations will only use SharedResource, rather than the resource for each class.

**What I actually need to achieve is: defining which `DataAnnotations` will be localized from the `SharedResource.resx` file, and which one will be localized from ViewModel-specific.resx file. Is this somehow possible?** In other words, I do not want to localize from different `*.resx` sources (where the fall-back value is the `SharedResource.resx`).

Comment: I don't think that is possible. If you specify .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization() without any special option, the class-specific resx files will be used. If you use the option shown in your example, then the shared resx file will be used. I don't think there is any middle way between these options and I don't think that there is a fallback from the class-specific file to the shared resx file. It might be possible to write your own implementation of IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizerFactory (but I personally doubt if that is a good idea).

Comment: There is a link to an implementation of IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizerFactory from [this page](https://andrewlock.net/localising-the-displayattribute-and-avoiding-magic-strings-in-asp-net-core/). The link is to [this project](https://github.com/andrewlock/blog-examples/tree/master/adding-localization-part-2/AddingLocalization). I have no idea it works.

Comment: @PhilJollans, it is not an implementation. He is trying to find a workaround the lacked `DisplayName` localization (which is now fixed in .Net Core 2.0).

Comment: I understand. I just thought that, if you wanted to make a custom implementation of IStringLocalizer to fix your problem, that might be a starting point.

Comment: He is also not implementing a new one, it would be good if he were doing this. He is just using a legacy method for that. Not implementing a new one.

Comment: Did you found the solution for this ?

Comment: @Jean-Francois, check my added answer, I gave a link to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered in another question bellow, thank's for @Tseng:

[How to change ViewModel display name without using `DisplayNameAttribute`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034655/how-to-change-viewmodel-display-name-without-using-displaynameattribute/48035865#48035865)