# How to change ViewModel display name without using `DisplayNameAttribute`?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to change the display name of some properties (of ViewModel) directly without using `[DisplayName("prop name")]`. This should happen either **directly inside the controller** before returning the View, or **inside the ViewModel class itself**.

I do NOT want to change anything in the View, and I do not want to use any data annotations. How can I achieve that?

Is there any fluent syntax maybe to get that?

I am using: **ASP.Net Core 2.0**

The problem with data annotations is that I want to get my display name in run time (while data annotations are pre-compiled).

## UPDATE:

The main reason for asking this question was to **find a way to wrap the `IStringLocalizer` and particularly its behavior when localizing data annotations**. The accepted answer explains the basics of that well.

Comment: why not have label properties on the view model and use that inside the view, then you can assign the labels from the controller action

Comment: @JoeAudette, That is what I wanted to do. I was just looking for more elegant way (it there is), where the property and its name are "coupled".

Comment: What exactly is your issue with `DisplayNameAttribute` or more specifically `Display`? Localization? It [should work](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/830983a477e19cfb7527e1caba3624a8424397a6/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations/Internal/DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider.cs#L117) since ASP.NET Core 1.1

Comment: Also in case you don't want to use precompiled resource files, you can use database as the source, see damienbod's [example](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreLocalization)

Comment: @Tseng, localization is exactly my problem. I am not comfortable with .Net Core localization solution. The main problem with it, is that I do not like that ALL attributes will be localized from the same file. It would be perfect if I can exactly say which attribute should be localized and from which file. Therefore, I wanted to implement my own localization middleware (or even simply a static class localization solution), but I still cannot localize `DisplayName`.

Comment: You can still do that, if you either override the default implementation of `IDisplayMetadataProvider`, in case you are not happy with the default implementation. Here a [minimalistic example](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2706#issuecomment-248049748) for `DisplayNameAttribute` from last year but within it you can choose which class/resource file to use basically

Comment: Why you do not use a XML file for the key value pairs, file which you can update at run time

Comment: Also according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#dataannotations-localization) can use separate resource files (first example uses naming conventions of the ViewModel where the attributes are located on)

Comment: @Tseng, sorry I should have said that more clearly, I meant that we should use either naming convention, or SharedResources. but not both, I have many cases where I have a lot of shared resources, and many ViewModel-specific strings (so a mixture). That is not achievable with .Net Core localization solution.

Comment: Yes, help us understand why you want to **do this inside the controller**?

Comment: @dev8989, because I want to pass localized text to it in runtime, I want to use very different sources for localization for each `Disaply` attribute (and actually for every attribute in my ViewModel).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> @Tseng, sorry I should have said that more clearly, I meant that we should use either naming convention, or SharedResources. but not both, I have many cases where I have a lot of shared resources, and many ViewModel-specific strings (so a mixture). That is not achievable with .Net Core localization solution.

If your only worries is that you can or can't determine if one or multiple resource files are chosen, that can easily be configured. I had to dig a bit in the source code, bit its seems possible.

As we can see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations/Internal/DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider.cs#L105-L108) the `localizer` is determined by the factory defined in the configuration

```
if (_stringLocalizerFactory != null && _localizationOptions.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider != null)
{
    localizer = _localizationOptions.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider(containerType, _stringLocalizerFactory);
}
```

whereas `_localizationOptions` is `MvcDataAnnotationsLocalizationOptions`.

The default implementation of `MvcDataAnnotationsLocalizationOptions` is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations/Internal/MvcDataAnnotationsLocalizationOptionsSetup.cs#L22-L23):

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public void Configure(MvcDataAnnotationsLocalizationOptions options)
{
    if (options == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    }

    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (modelType, stringLocalizerFactory) =>
        stringLocalizerFactory.Create(modelType);
}
```

So it uses per model resources by default.

You can change that to a `SharedResource` file for all data annotations if you like, with the following in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` (untested, but should work):

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
    });
```

This will effectively ignore the passed type and always return a shared string localizer.

Of course, you can add any logic there and decide on type-per-type case which localizer you are going to use.

#### Edit

If that's not enough, you can implement your own custom `IDisplayMetadataProvider` which handles it the way you want. But using the `DisplayAttribute` should be enough actually. `DisplayAttribute` has additional parameters which allow you to define the resource type.

```
[Display(Name = "StringToLocalize", ResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
```

With the `ResourceType` you can choose the class (and hence the resource file name) used to look up for the localization.

#### Edit 2: Using a wrapped `IStringLocalizer` with fallback to per-viewmodel resource

The more elegant solution involves using the above `MvcDataAnnotationsLocalizationOptions` options file to return your own `IStringLocalizer` which looks into one resource file and falls back to the other one.

```
public class DataAnnotationStringLocalizer : IStringLocalizer
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer primaryLocalizer;
    private readonly IStringLocalizer fallbackLocalizer;

    public DataAnnotationStringLocalizer(IStringLocalizer primaryLocalizer, IStringLocalizer fallbackLocalizer)
    {
        this.primaryLocalizer = primaryLocalizer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(primaryLocalizer));
        this.fallbackLocalizer = fallbackLocalizer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fallbackLocalizer));
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            LocalizedString localizedString = primaryLocalizer[name];
            if (localizedString.ResourceNotFound)
            {
                localizedString = fallbackLocalizer[name];
            }

            return localizedString;
        }
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments]
    {
        get
        {
            LocalizedString localizedString = primaryLocalizer[name, arguments];
            if (localizedString.ResourceNotFound)
            {
                localizedString = fallbackLocalizer[name, arguments];
            }

            return localizedString;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<LocalizedString> GetAllStrings(bool includeParentCultures)
        => primaryLocalizer.GetAllStrings(includeParentCultures).Concat(fallbackLocalizer.GetAllStrings(includeParentCultures));

    public IStringLocalizer WithCulture(CultureInfo culture)
        => new DataAnnotationStringLocalizer(primaryLocalizer.WithCulture(culture), fallbackLocalizer.WithCulture(culture));
}
```

And with the following options

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
        {
            return new DataAnnotationStringLocalizer(
                factory?.Create(typeof(SharedResource)),
                factory?.Create(type)
            );
        };
    });
```

Now, the string is first resolved from the shared resource and if the string wasn't found there, it will resolve it from the view model type (type parameter passed to the factory method).

If you don't like the logic and you want that it first looks into the view-model resource files, you just change the order to

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
        {
            return new DataAnnotationStringLocalizer(
                factory?.Create(type),
                factory?.Create(typeof(SharedResource))
            );
        }
    });
```

Now the view model is the primary resolver and shared resource the secondary

Comment: I have exactly the pages you mentioned opened in my browser and trying to understand how to solve it. I think my solution will be in implementing my custom `IStringLocalizer` or its factory. I am still not sure. I have to finish reading the source code, hopefully I can understand exactly what it does. I will write to you when I finish it.

Comment: *If that's not enough, you can implement your own custom IDisplayMetadataProvider which handles it*. I did not get exactly who is this **it**?

Comment: Yea, I was just working on additional example where you create a custom localizer which accepts two localizers, one for the shared resource and one for the model, then you check if the string exists in the shared resource, if not look up in the viewmodel resource

Comment: Such an example (custom localizer) would be really great for me and for others I believe!

Comment: See this example https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2706#issuecomment-248049748. It's obsolete now cause the `DisplayNameAttribute` Code has now been moved into `DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider`, but it shows how to add and register your own `IXxxMetadataProvider`

Comment: Is `DisplayName` different from `Display`? actually I did not care about that but I now realize that I mixed them in my code (mostly I used `Display( Name = "xxx")`, but in two places `DisplayName("xxx")`).

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: They are a bit different. `DisplayNameAttribute` doesn't have the properties that `DisplayName`have, it has just a parameterless constructor and `Name`. Wheras `DisplayAttribute` has `Name`, `Description`, `ResourceType` and more. But both are now implemented in `DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider` (which wasn't the case when ASP.NET Core 1.0 was released)

Comment: Updated my answer. Untested though other than "it compiles" ;) Next time just provide sufficient information in the initial question, makes it easier to bring in a solution when the exact reasons for not wanting to use the ASP.NET Core localization. The localization system is **VERY** flexible and customizable

Comment: Thanks a lot! :), I am still trying to get it working with `IDisplayMetadataProvider`. When I finish this I will try the custom `IStringLocalizer` you wrote. I will let you know when I try it.

Comment: I have not tested `MvcDataAnnotationsLocalizationOptions` solution yet (I just read it), but it seems to be working. The information I got from you here are pretty awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Here I am concerned about something. Here we create `DataAnnotationStringLocalizer` using `new`. Will it be disposed? I read before that the DI will not dispose the services registered like this.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: Neither one uses unmanaged resources, so there's nothing to dispose and worry about. Neither `ResourceManagerStringLocalizer` nor `StringLocalizer` implements `IDisposable`. M.E.DI calls dispose where `IDisposable` is is implemented and resolved via M:E.DI, all others will get disposed when they are not referenced anymore and the GC feels like it

Comment: What is M.E.DI?

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` :P

Comment: Lol ok, that makes sense, therefore google could not find that xD.