# Localize `Required` annotation in French implicitly

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

TLDR; 
How to get the behaviour of

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Le champ {0} est obligatoire")]
```

while only writing

```
[Required]
```

---

As I understand it the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) does not provide a way to implicitly localize a given set of DataAnnotations.

I would like to have the error messages for annotations such as `Required` and `StringLength` be over-rideable without touching others such as `Display` and without the need to explicitly specify the translation using the `ErrorMessage` attribute.

note: I only need to have the messages translated in French, so there is no need for the solution to be bound to the request's language.

**I tried the following:**

From [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/issues/187) GitHub thread

In the `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.AttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor =
    (value, name) => $"Hmm, '{value}' is not a valid value for '{name}'."));
```

Gives me the following error

> Property or indexer 'DefaultModelBindingMessageProvider.AttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

And I could not find any property that might work as a setter for this object.

---

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50230263/6838730) SO answer

In the `Startup.cs`
    services.AddSingleton();

and create a class like follow

```
public class LocalizedValidationAttributeAdapterProvider : IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider
{
    private readonly ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider _originalProvider = new ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider();

    public IAttributeAdapter GetAttributeAdapter(ValidationAttribute attribute, IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer)
    {
        /* override message */
    }
}
```

But this only captured the `DataType` annotation

Comment: How did you you it for the DataAnnotation attributes like Required and StringLength? The accepted solution is only for the Model binding errors, not for DataAnnotation attributes like you've asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .Net Core 2, the `Accessor` properties in `ModelBindingMessageProvider` are read-only, but you can still set them by using the `Set...Accessor()` methods.  Here's code similar to what I'm using, with thanks to the answer to [ASP.NET Core Model Binding Error Messages Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828570/asp-net-core-model-binding-error-messages-localization).

```
public static class ModelBindingConfig
{
    public static void Localize(MvcOptions opts)
    {
        opts.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingBindRequiredValueAccessor(
            x => string.Format("A value for the '{0}' property was not provided.", x)
        );

        opts.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingKeyOrValueAccessor(
            () => "A value is required."
        );
    }
}


// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddMvc(
        opts =>
        {
            ModelBindingConfig.Localize(opts);
        })
        .AddViewLocalization()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}
```