# Simply Change culture for [Required] data annotation validation message in .net Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations, asp.net-core-localization

What I'm trying to do seems really simple but I'm struggling with it since this morning...

I just want to force French language for html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Name)

Here my name property :

```cs
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Right now, if I try to validate a form without filling the property I've got the "The Name field is required."

1. Where does this message "The {0} is required." come from ?
2. How can I change the language of it without having to override all my [Required] properties in all my ViewModels with something like :

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName ="Required",ErrorMessageResourceType =typeof(FrenchDataAnnotation))]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please have a look on  [`this thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888963/localize-required-annotation-in-french-implicitly)? Are you looking for this?

Comment: As Alexandre Jobin pointed in OP answer, this does work only for Model binding errors, not for DataAnnotation like Required and StringLength.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validation attribute that implements the default `Required` attribute and use it for validation:

```cs
public sealed class ExRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public ExRequiredAttribute() : base()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "my custom error message...!"
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```cs
[ExRequired]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Another solution is to use third party localization nuget like [`XLocalizer`](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/index.md) which overrides all default [data annotations](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/localizing-validation-attributes-errors.md), [ModelBinding](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/model-binding-errors.md) and [IdentityErrors](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/identity-errors.md).