# DataAnnotations localization in asp net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, data-annotations

I'm trying to implement this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dataannotations-localization

My code:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
    });
...
}
```

SharedResource.cs

```
namespace MyProj.Classes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dummy class to group shared resources
    /// </summary>
    public class SharedResource
    {

    }
}
```

FooViewModel.cs

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "EmailRequired")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "EmailIsNotValid")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

FooPage.cshtml

```
...
<input asp-for="Email" class="form-control">
<div class="invalid-feedback" style="display:block;">
    <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
</div>
...
```

And I have the resource file Resources\SharedResource.resx

**Email**   Email
**EmailIsNotValid** The Email field is not a valid email address.
**EmailRequired**   The Email field is required.

Doesn't work, no errors during compilation or runtime. Instead of a translation, it shows me 'EmailIsNotValid' or 'EmailRequired'. What could go wrong?

Comment: You want the `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` properties rather than `ErrorMessage`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How localize ErrorMessage in DataAnnotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699594/how-localize-errormessage-in-dataannotation)

Comment: I assume things changed since mvc 5, in official docs there's no ErrorMessageResourceName/Type info (in my link). It might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769199/localization-of-requiredattribute-in-asp-net-core-2-0

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  This is .net core.  It handles localization differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [Localization of RequiredAttribute in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769199/localization-of-requiredattribute-in-asp-net-core-2-0) But there are no marked answers and it's hidden in the comments.

Dummy SharedResource class should be in the same namespace as a web application (startup.cs). In my case, I removed '.classes'. Docs were unclear.

update:
for dummy classes as mine same file name rules apply as in docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#resource-file-naming

> Resources are named for the full type name of their class minus the
>   assembly name. For example, a French resource in a project whose main
>   assembly is LocalizationWebsite.Web.dll for the class
>   LocalizationWebsite.Web.Startup would be named Startup.fr.resx. A
>   resource for the class
>   LocalizationWebsite.Web.Controllers.HomeController would be named
>   Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx. If your targeted class's namespace
>   isn't the same as the assembly name you will need the full type name.
>   For example, in the sample project a resource for the type
>   ExtraNamespace.Tools would be named ExtraNamespace.Tools.fr.resx.

Another workaround would be to name resource file as 'Classes.SharedResource.resx' or put it in a folder Resources\Classes.

Comment: Maybe dummy SharedResource class should be in the same root namespace, not full (meaning folder name is not important)?